# How can I rewrite URL in my case

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have read related Q&A's for this is question, but still I am confused on this, can somebody help me on this?
**What I am doing**: my url is : www.mysite.com/home.php
 I have two files: home.php and get_data.php, in home.php i am calling get_data.php with the use of jquery. the code for jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                   $("#btn_submit").bind('click', function(){
                   $.get('/get_data.php?tnm='+$('#tnm').val(), '', function(data){
                $('#get_info').html(data);
        });
    }); });
```

Here #tnm is name of the textbox & #get_info is the id of div tag. I am accessing $_GET['tnm'] in get_data.php.
**What I want is**: When I search username with : www.mysite.com/username, I should get that user's result accordingly. How can I rewrite the url for this? Please help! Please feel free for any details.

Comment: Why is the rewrited URL if you loading pages with AJAX? (btw pls accept some answers if possible)

Comment: I may not be able properly explain fabrik, see this is twitterapi based site, suppose user 'A' visits site with "www.mysite.com/A" , he should get his result page. any suggestion on this?

Comment: In this case the only thing you need is mod_rewrite. The js snippet blindfold and irrelevant in this case. You can simply create rewrite rules with .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why you are trying to use .HTACCESS for Ajax calls, any way http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html is  the best place  :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this plugin it can be useful.
[jquery.address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/)

Comment: sorry, I thought if you want to update URL after fetching content via ajax so that it can be bookmarked for direct access.